# best practice: file open/close operations

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

So: we're studying what the textbook calls "advanced file operations", and I'm writing a nice little inventory program. Simple question: what's more efficient/considered best: to open the file in main and send it by reference to the various functions (one each for adding to, reading from, and altering), or to let each function open and close the file as needed? Any real advantage either way?

Comment: An advantage to closing the files after each operation is it will flush the files, so if the program crashes you won't lose as much data. You could do the same thing keeping the files open, by flushing after each function. Note flushing has a performance cost.

Comment: This hardly depends on your usage scenario and is not a good question for SO, read the FAQ: http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in my personal experiences and opinions its cleaner to just make a file reader function that has the filename passed in, and another one for writing.

if you did the functions in main() it would get ugly really fast if you process multiple files.