# Is opening and closing a PrintWriter object repeatedly bad practice in Java?

Tags: java, logging, filewriter, printwriter, bufferedwriter

I'm trying to write a really simple Java logging class that can write to a log file so I can reuse it in my other projects. I extended the `PrintWriter` class so I could detect if the log file was open or not before writing to it.

When the user is finished logging, they must call `.close()` on the logging object to close the file. When only integrated into a single-class application, this isn't that big of a deal, but now I'm trying to integrate this logger class into several different parent and child classes that will all reference the same log file, and without closing one reference, I won't be able to open another from a different class.

Would it be terrible to call `.open()`, `.write(msg)`, `.close()` every time something is logged? It *would* eliminate the need to `open` and `close` the logger manually. Or **is there a better solution?**

I found [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15950267/best-practice-file-open-close-operations) for C++, but the only answer was "in my experience..." and I'm kind of looking for a more in-depth answer.

Comment: I think this is inherently opinion based, but generally opening and closing a file (or constantly re-creating objects) is bad practice.  OTOH logging tends to be something that one does relatively seldom, so it doesn't always make sense to try to optimize it.  If you are having problems, use a profiler.  If you aren't having problems, "if it ain't broke don't fix it."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would not recommend multiple classes writing in the same file concurrently. My idea will be to implement a queue for your `Logger` class in which all the classes integrated with it will `push` their logs to.

Whenever a class push its logs to the queue it should ask the logger to `write` to the file.

Create a boolean `writing` in your `Logger` instance that prevents multiple `write` commands to be executed to avoid any duplication.

Your `write` method keeps writing until the queue is empty and then resets the `writing` boolean to `false`.

```
// A sample logger class
public class Logger {
  static Queue<String> pending = new LinkedList<String>();
  static boolean writing = false;
  static PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter("production.log", "UTF-8");

  public static void write() {
    if(!writing) {
      writing = true;
      pw.open();
      while(!pending.isEmpty()) {
        pw.println(pending.poll());
      }
      pw.close();
      writing = false;
    }
  }
}
```

You now `open` and `close` your file less frequently and you do not lose any of your logs.

Comment: I like this idea a lot. At this stage, I'm not planning on using the logger class in any kind of multi-threaded system, though, so in a single thread, this would essentially function the same as `opening` `writing` and then `closing`, right?

Comment: If only one class writes to it at a time and no simultaneous writing then it is the same as opening and closing